# Facebook Graph Api -- Can I get the "default" fields plus some?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When I make a request to https://graph.facebook.com/me -- I get a large JSON object with lots of good data in it.

However, I want to also get the user's cover photo (if it exists). Is there a way to do this, while also retaining the default fields?

For instance: https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=cover -- returns just the cover image.

If I use one field, do I need to specify exactly the other fields that I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to either itemise all the fields you want, or accept the defaults, there's no way to get 'defaults + these other fields'